# Self-Avoiding Random Walk - Compiled Program won't execute

Tags: python, intellij-idea, random-walk

I'm trying to run a Self Avoiding Random Walk program using IntelliJ with the code below. The program compiles successfully however, after calling it - the terminal goes to the next line with a blank (doesn't reset) and nothing is printed out. I'm not able to call any new programs or type in the terminal as well.

```
public class SelfAvoidingRandomWalks {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int trials = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int deadEnds = 0;
    for (int t = 0; t < trials; t++) {
        boolean[][] a = new boolean[n][n];
        int x = n / 2, y = n / 2;
        while (x > 0 && x < (n - 1) && y > 0 && y < (n - 1)) ;
        {
            a[x][y] = true;
            if (a[x - 1][y] && a[x + 1][y] && a[x][y - 1] && a[x][y + 1]) {
                deadEnds++;
                break;
            }
            double r = Math.random();
            if (r < 0.25) {
                if (!a[x + 1][y]) x++;
            }
            else if (r < 0.50) {
                if (!a[x - 1][y]) x--;
            }
            else if (r < 0.75) {
                if (!a[x][y + 1]) y++;
            }
            else if (r < 1.00) {
                if (!a[x][y - 1]) y--;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(100 * (deadEnds / trials) + "% dead ends");
    System.out.println(deadEnds);
}
```

}